# How to appear a button when we click on another button kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem for some time, I try to make a button appear when I click on another button.

main.py

```
#Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os

class StatisticsPlusApp(MDApp):

    firstteam = ObjectProperty(None)
    secondteam = ObjectProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("startscreen.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("loginscreen.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("mainscreen.kv"))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return screen_manager

    def btn(self):
        print("First Team:", self.firstteam.text, "Second Team:", self.secondteam.text)
        filename = self.firstteam.text + "_VS_" + self.secondteam.text + "_Match" + ".txt"
        statsfile = open(filename, "w+")
        statsfile.write(self.firstteam.text + " VS " + self.secondteam.text + " MATCH")
        statsfile.close()
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            print("Good !")
        else:
            print("Not Good !")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    StatisticsPlusApp().run()
```

So if someone has the answer to this problem, could he answer me please, Thanks :) MajinBlux

Comment: add minimum runnable code

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [link](https://youtu.be/0TZBtpfIKcc). To add a button through another button. You need to call a function that adds another button through the button.

Example

```
    on_press: root.add_widget(Button)
```